# Dimming chase on Applescript

Tags: macos, display, applescript

I would like to create an automated brightness/dimming chase on my Mac OS Yosemite 10.10.5 using Applescript,

I found this script>>

**Dimmer:** tell application "System Events"
        key code 107
    end tell

**Brighter:** tell application "System Events"
        key code 113
    end tell

What I would like to do now is to repeat that action and control the speed/timeframe of the dimming,

Any Applescript expert able to help on that?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Only because you asked... The *code* below is an example of using a `repeat` *statement* and `delay` *commands* with your *code*.

That said, I do not believe it is going to give you the desired results because while the events will trigger in code nonetheless they'll probably not be processed at the hardware level. (It doesn't on my system.)

You can change the numeric value in the `repeat` *statement* to suite your needs. The *value* is an *integer*, as in `repeat integer [times]`.

The `delay` *command* shown in *decimal seconds* as in `delay number` being the number of seconds to delay. The number may be fractional, such as 0.5 to delay half a second.

---

```
repeat 3 times
    repeat 10 times
        tell application "System Events"
            key code 107
        end tell
        delay (0.1)
    end repeat
    repeat 10 times
        tell application "System Events"
            key code 113
        end tell
        delay (0.1)
    end repeat
end repeat
```

Comment: Hey cool, thanks !!! this is really helpful! I'll just play with the value now